# How to pass arguments to a Google Benchmark Program

Tags: c++, google-api, parameter-passing, benchmarking, google-benchmark

I have a C++ Google Benchmark Program. It uses Google's `BENCHMARK_MAIN()` method. Now I call and execute the compiled program with a Go script. Is there a way to pass arguments into my benchmark program? (I know the common way over a main method, but I'm not sure how to do it in Googletest, because it's implemented in `benchmark_api.h` and I can't just change that.)

Update:

So far I copied out the macro body into my `benchmark.cpp` and added a line. It is not a nice solution because possible changes from Google on this Macro (like a name changing or an added code line) wouldn't affect my copy. It is working at last.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyNamespace::conf = {argv[1]};
    ::benchmark::Initialize (&argc, argv);
    ::benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks ();
}
```

Comment: What arguments do you want to pass to the program? It the arguments are for google benchmark then just call the program and append the arguments for example `./prog_name --benchmark_format=json`.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What did that tell you?

Comment: @MikevanDyke I want to pass two integer values and a string, because it is meant to be a generic benchmark. I wanna add a chunk size and an iteration count for a loop inside the used function to benchmark and the name of the used function in the benchmark test itself. This way I wanna run single, are modifiable Benchmarks manually trough a go script.

Comment: So far I just copied out the body of the 'BENCHMARK_MAIN()' makro (the main method). So now I don't use the makro anymore but the the body of that, which I modified now to use the first passed Argument and put it into a variable.

Comment: This approach is now mentioned in the official docs, so it ought to be stable: https://github.com/google/benchmark#using-registerbenchmarkname-fn-args
You can also pass your args in to `benchmark::RegisterBenchmark` via `->Arg(...)`, rather than using a global variable.

Answer (score 6):

Hacking the whole `BENCHMARK_MAIN` function is of course one way to do it, but IMO it's really cumbersome and really ugly. So I'm just gonna propose a different approach:

```
// define your chunksize and iteration count combinations here (for i and j) 
static void CustomArguments(benchmark::internal::Benchmark* b) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j <= 50; ++j)
      b->Args({i, j});
}

// the string (name of the used function is passed later)
static void TestBenchmark(benchmark::State& state, std::string func_name) {
  // cout for testing purposes
  std::cout << state.range(0) /* = i */ << " " << state.range(1) /* = j */ 
  << " " << func_name << std::endl;
  for (auto _ : state) {
     // do whatever with i and j and func_name
  }
}

// This macro is used to pass the string "function_name1/2/3" 
// as a parameter to TestBenchmark
BENCHMARK_CAPTURE(TestBenchmark, benchmark_name1, "function_name1")
    ->Apply(CustomArguments);
BENCHMARK_CAPTURE(TestBenchmark, benchmark_name2, "function_name2")
    ->Apply(CustomArguments);
BENCHMARK_CAPTURE(TestBenchmark, benchmark_name3, "function_name3")
    ->Apply(CustomArguments);

BENCHMARK_MAIN()
```

And then in your go script, you call the benchmark with a regex filter:
`./prog_name --benchmark_filter=InsertRegexFilterHere`

So for example:
`./prog_name --benchmark_filter=TestBenchmark/benchmark_name2/5/35`

The above example will call the benchmark and will pass "function_name2", 5 and 35 (these are the values for your chunksize and iteration count) and so the output will be something like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                       Time           CPU Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TestBenchmark/benchmark_name2/5/35               2 ns          2 ns  308047644
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to extend Mike van Dyke's answer by adding that the library also supports the following:

```
static void BM_SetInsert(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::set<int> data;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    state.PauseTiming();
    data = ConstructRandomSet(state.range(0));
    state.ResumeTiming();
    for (int j = 0; j < state.range(1); ++j)
      data.insert(RandomNumber());
  }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_SetInsert)
    ->Args({1<<10, 128})
    ->Args({2<<10, 128})
    ->Args({4<<10, 128})
    ->Args({8<<10, 128})
    ->Args({1<<10, 512})
    ->Args({2<<10, 512})
    ->Args({4<<10, 512})
    ->Args({8<<10, 512});
```

In your benchmark, `state.range(0)` and `state.range(1)` now refers to the first and second argument respectively. See more @ https://github.com/google/benchmark#passing-arguments

Answer (score 1):

As described in https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#using-registerbenchmarkname-fn-args, benchmarks can be registered interactively like so:

```cpp
auto BM_test = [](benchmark::State& st, auto Inputs) { /* ... */ };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  for (auto& test_input : { /* ... */ })
      benchmark::RegisterBenchmark(test_input.name(), BM_test, test_input);
  benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
  benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
  benchmark::Shutdown();
}
```

It should be noted that normally `benchmark` aborts if it sees unknown arguments. This is not the case for `benchmark::Initialize`. This function removes all `benchmark` specific options like `--benchmark_filter`, `--benchmark_out`... from `argv` and it leaves unknown options and positional arguments intact (`argc` is modified too).

This means that one can call

```cpp
benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
```

and then get program specific arguments from the cleaned `argc` and `argv`.