# How to pass input files to Google benchmark?

Tags: c++, google-benchmark

The benchmarked code requires some input. I have gathered the data in several files. I would like to run the benchmark like this:

```bash
./benchmark file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

The files should be then used as input to the benchmarked code. In my particular usecase, I have a set of benchmarks. The set of benchmarks should be run for every file specified in the command line.

Although I would prefer this to be handled by command line arguments like shown above, I accept any working solution that would allow passing files to the benchmarks.

I am new to Google benchmarks and I see no way to do such thing because the benchmark executable doesn't accept user data. The closest thing to this I have found in to documentation is https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#using-register-benchmark but I still have to pass `argc` and `argv` to `benchmark::Initialize`.

I could theoretically make my argument parsing which would accept files and would be compatible with Google benchmark executable's arguments and then make a modified version of `argc` and `argv` for `benchmark::Initialize` which would contain benchmark arguments but not the files. But this is a exaggeratedly complicated solution. And Google benchmarks probably expects the `argc` and `argv` to be the actual `argc` and `argv` of the program which could break it (for example some libraries I have used which provide their own main have a special mechanism for handling Windows' arguments which could somehow conflict with this).

## Questions

How am I supposed to run benchmarks which require files? Is that forbidden/not the intended use case of Google benchmark? Am I expected to hardcode the paths? I'm surely not the only one who wants to use files in benchmarks. Is passing external data to benchmarks undesired?

Comment: This post is a duplicate of the linked post, but none of the answers in the other post aren't applicable for my problem. The outlined solutions work for numbers only, not strings of filenames.

Comment: I think I have found a potential solution for this problem. I will direct my attention at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519376/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-google-benchmark-program and leave this question as is.